# Exe file wont launch after converting .py to .exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I have a project for minecraft, and after converting it to exe with this command:

`pyinstaller "F:\pythonprojetcs\minecraft file mover\splashscreen.py" -F --icon="F:\pythonprojetcs\minecraft file mover\app.ico"`

It wont launch. This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "splashscreen.py", line 21, in <module>
    image = tk.PhotoImage(file=image_file)
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4064, in __init__
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4009, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\REINER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI248722\data\image.png": no such file or directory
[4692] Failed to execute script splashscreen
```

It works fine when its in the .py format, with to errors.
Its says that tkinter is the error, but I don't understand it.

The code:

```
# create a splash screen, 80% of display screen size, centered,
# displaying a GIF image with needed info, disappearing after 5 seconds
import os
import tkinter as tk
import shutil
import time


root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width*0.8, height*0.8, width*0.1, height*0.1))

image_file = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '\\data\\image.png'
image = tk.PhotoImage(file=image_file)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=height*0.8, width=width*0.8, bg="brown")
canvas.create_image(width*0.8/2, height*0.8/2, image=image)
canvas.pack()

root.after(2000, root.destroy)
root.mainloop()

print("Világ vagy textúrát akkarsz? (világ = 1 / textúra = 2 / világ másolás = 3 / tutorial = 4)")
choosing = input()

if choosing == "1":
    print("\n")
    print("\n")
    print("Ok, szóval világ.")
    print("Hol van?")
    original = input()
    target = 'C:\\Users\\Refi\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\saves'
    shutil.move(original,target)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Kész!")
    print("Ha ezt írja ki: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Reiner Regő\\Downloads\\test', akkor az a fálj nem létezik!")
    print("Kérlek várj! Ne zárd be!")
    time.sleep(3)
if choosing == "2":
    print("\n")
    print("\n")
    print("Ok, szóval textúra.")
    print("Hol van?")
    original = input()
    target = 'C:\\Users\\Refi\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\resourcepacks'
    shutil.move(original,target)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Kész!")
    print("Ha ezt írja ki: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Reiner Regő\\Downloads\\test', akkor az a fálj nem létezik!")
    print("Kérlek várj! Ne zárd be!")
    time.sleep(3)

if choosing == "3":
    print("\n")
    print("\n")
    print("Ok, szóval világot akarsz másolni.")
    print("Mi a neve?")
    inputfromuser = input()
    original = 'C:\\Users\\Refi\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\saves\\' + inputfromuser
    target = 'D:'
    shutil.move(original,target)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Kész! A D:-ben fogod megtlálni!")
    print("Ha ezt írja ki: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Refi\\Downloads', akkor az a fálj nem létezik!")
    print("Kérlek várj! Ne zárd be!")
    time.sleep(3)

    print('\n')
    input("nyomd meg az entert a kilépéshez")
```

This copies files from one diretory from another, the splashscreen code is just an example.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is trying to access image files from a directory relative to the script itself; this works when the script is installed unpacked, with resources actually on the file system. But when bundled into an executable, that can't work; the image isn't going to be there unless you've copied it in with the executable (an ugly hack of a solution); you need to bundle it into the executable itself in such a way that it can be extracted at runtime by your script.

You need to read [the docs on spec files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html), specifically, [adding data files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) (to bundle the data with the executable when you build it) and [using data files from a module](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-data-files-from-a-module) (to extract the bundled data in memory at runtime).

You'll only have access to the *data* from the file, it won't be a file on disk anymore, so you'll need to [use alternate means of loading, e.g. from base64 encoded data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42834675/364696).