# How to embed a base64 image into python 3 guizero/tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, base64, guizero

I am trying to embed a base64 image into either a box or the picture widget so my application requires less files. I found a way to do it with plain tkinter at [Base64 string to image in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834675/base64-string-to-image-in-tkinter) answered by Bryan Oakley and I updated the code to work with python 3.

**What they did**

```
import tkinter as tk

IMAGE_DATA = '''
    R0lGODlhEAAQALMAAAAAAP//AP///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQABAAQAQ3UMgpAKC4hm13uJnWgR
    TgceZJllw4pd2Xpagq0WfeYrD7\n2i5Yb+aJyVhFHAmnazE/z4tlSq0KIgA7\n
    '''

root = tk.Tk()
image = tk.PhotoImage(data=IMAGE_DATA)
label = tk.Label(root, image=image, padx=20, pady=20)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**What I've tried**

```
import tkinter as tk
from guizero import *
import base64

app= App()

#the same image they used for testing
IMAGE_DATA = '''
    R0lGODlhEAAQALMAAAAAAP//AP///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAA\nAAAAACH5BAEAAAIALAAAAAAQABAAQAQ3UMgpAKC4hm13uJnWgR
    TgceZJllw4pd2Xpagq0WfeYrD7\n2i5Yb+aJyVhFHAmnazE/z4tlSq0KIgA7\n
    '''

box=Box(app,width=app.width,height=app.height)
box.bg='gray'


#button=PushButton(app, image=IMAGE_DATA)
#image =  Picture(box, image=IMAGE_DATA)
#picText = Text(box, tk.data=IMAGE_DATA)

#Pure tkinter
'''
image = tk.PhotoImage(data=IMAGE_DATA)
label = tk.Label(box, image=image, padx=20, pady=20)
label.pack()
'''

app.display()
```

**What I used**

- https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/ (module)
- https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image (converts images to base 64)

Comment: I've never used guizero, but have you tried `image=tk.PhotoImage(data=IMAGE_DATA)`?

Comment: I just, it works thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `image` option requires an instance of the `PhotoImage` class from tkinter. So, create an instance, and pass that to guizero widget.

```
image = tk.PhotoImage(data=IMAGE_DATA)
button=PushButton(app, image=image)
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the image size?

Comment: @PurpleLlama: there are many questions on this site about resizing tkinter images.

Comment: I found the zoom but could not find anything about how to dynamically size it into a box